# How to get exitcode from Powershell and return to CMD?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a powershell script. I run my powershell script using a CMD file. I want to get the exit code from my powershell script and return the value to the CMD.
I tried this. but it does not return the exitcode, when I execute the CMD file to call the powershell.

#### PowerShell Script

```
$SN = "17A1"
$BID = "#SBCM#DBCM"
$FB = "UdpdqfP.Bd"

$SN2 = Get-Content .\out4 | Where-Object{$_.Contains("$SN")}

if($SN2)
{
    Write-Host "OK"
}
else{
    Write-Host "Not ok"
   $ExitCode = "ExitCode"
   $ExitCode = "123"
   Exit $ExitCode
}
```

#### CMD to call the powershell and return the exitcode

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File %~dp0\test.ps1
ECHO %ExitCode%
Exit /b %ExitCode%
```

I execute the CMD file, and return this:

```
D:\XX\>powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File D:\XX\\test.ps1
Not ok

D:\XX\>ECHO
ECHO is on.

D:\XX\>Exit /b
```

My expectation once I execute the CMD file:

```
D:\Boot_Order>powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File D:\Boot_Order\\test.ps1
Not ok

D:\Boot_Order>ECHO
123

D:\Boot_Order>Exit /b 123
```

Comment: A clear methodology to handle exit codes in PowerShell and cmd is not straightforward. https://weblogs.asp.net/soever/returning-an-exit-code-from-a-powershell-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch files work with the environment variable `%errorlevel%` so change the batch file to:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%~dp0\test.ps1"
echo %errorlevel%
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

Comment: This does not work as expected. Tried this with test.ps1 having 
exit 10
but errorlevel ending up as 1. DOS is made as useless as possible

Comment: Is there any other command between the `echo` and `exit` line in your script, @gk_2000